# Javascript/jQuery close notification fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have made a basic sticky notification that shows on my website, I am trying to make it so you can manually close it by clicking a button but it won't seem to work? Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#closeBtn").click(function () {
            $(".notification").fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="notification" id="success">
    Message sent
    <a href="#" id="closeBtn">
        <div class="close">
            <div class="closeTxt">X</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: is the notification element created dynamically?

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/szn8H/) - or is it the "sticky" part that you're having trouble with, that you don't want the notification to come back after a page refresh?

Comment: Not right now, it will be shown if the message has been sent and the text inside it will change dependant on that

Comment: No, it won't fade out for me :/

Comment: can you check whether the `click` handler is called by adding a `console.log('clicked')` to the handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using  [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  for the elements created dynamically

```
$(document).on('click','#closeBtn',function() {
  $(".notification").fadeOut(500); 
   return false;   
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the element is added to the DOM after page load, you need to use `.on()` instead of `.click()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#closeBtn', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.notification').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the element is added Dynamically you have two choices.

```
    function myFadeOut() {
        $(".notification").fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    }
```

Using the on:

```
$(document).on('click', '#closeBtn', myFadeOut);
```

Or more clean, adding the click directly on the node when you generate it:

```
var $myNode = $('<div class="someNode"></div>');
$myNode.click( myFadeOut);
$(".foobar").append($myNode);
```